# How can I background launching a graphical linux program on the windows subsystem?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I've installed the windows subsystem, xming, and in the linux system urxvt.
I'm trying to launch urxvt without keeping a cmd window open.
So far I've tried running:

```
bash -c urxvt
```

Keeps a cmd window open.

```
bash -c "urxvt" &
```

Opens a terminal window which closes instantly.

```
cmd /c "bash -c urxvt" & exit
```

Which also keeps the cmd window open.

```
bash -c "nohup urxvt &"
```

Creates no window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to background tasks which don't require a terminal window by running them through a vbs script.

```
set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
ws.run "bash -c urxvtd -q -o -f", 0
```

The following will run the urxvt daemon or any other program within the quotes without creating a window.
Then the urxvt client (urxvtc,) can be run with:

```
bash -c urxvtc
```

Credit and more information on the [WSFL github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/612)